# PHP: Simplest way to delete a folder (including its contents)

Tags: php, file-io, delete-directory

The `rmdir()` function fails if the folder contains any files.  I can loop through all of the the files in the directory with something like this:

```
foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
    if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') continue;
    unlink($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$item);
}
rmdir($dir);
```

Is there any way to just delete it all at once?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Well, there's always

```
system('/bin/rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($dir));
```

where available.

Comment: @KashifRaza: Right. Hence "where available".

Comment: On Windows use this:

    system('rd /Q /S "' . $dir . '"');

Answer (score 63):

`rrmdir()` -- recursively delete directories:

```
function rrmdir($dir) { 
  foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) { 
    if(is_dir($file)) rrmdir($file); else unlink($file); 
  } rmdir($dir); 
}
```

Comment: I once delete my whole project using such function, be careful!

Comment: @gskema, Your comment made me laugh!!! I can only imagine the "ohhhh shhiiiiittttt" moment. I hope you got it all back!

Comment: @silversunhunter Actually, I didn't. When `unlink` deletes something, it means it. Good thing that it was only a test project. Lesson of the day: use a remote VCS

Comment: @gskema, I sympathize. I literally just deleted my entire website by accident. Thank god I've got a backup.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb Your name checks out :D

Comment: delete whole project folder: `rrmdir('.');` :)

Answer (score 3):

```
function delete_files($dir) {
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $objects = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
      if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
        if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") 
           delete_files($dir."/".$object); 
        else unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
      }
    }
    reset($objects);
    rmdir($dir);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [this](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) source;

Save some time, if you want to clean a directory or delete it and you're on windows.

Use This:

```
    chdir ($file_system_path);
    exec ("del *.* /s /q");
```

You can use other DEL syntax, or any other shell util.
You may have to allow the service to interact with the desktop, as that's my current setting and I'm not changing it to test this.

Else you could find an alternative method [here.](http://aidanlister.com/2004/04/recursively-deleting-a-folder-in-php/)

Comment: it's a bad idea to have to depend on your OS... this only works on Windows and would fail on a Unix system for instance...

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
exec('rm -rf '.$user_dir);
```

Comment: never ever! you must esape $user_dir! please add escapeshellarg($user_dir)

Comment: unsafe and worse: depends on your OS... this would fail on a windows system for instance...

Answer (score 1):

This fuction delete the directory and all subdirectories and files:

```
function DelDir($target) {
    if(is_dir($target)) {
        $files = glob( $target . '*', GLOB_MARK ); //GLOB_MARK adds a slash to directories returned

        foreach( $files as $file )
        {
            DelDir( $file );      
        }

        rmdir( $target );
    } elseif(is_file($target)) {
        unlink( $target );  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One safe and good function located in php comments by lprent
It prevents accidentally deleting contents of symbolic links directories located in current directory

```
public static function delTree($dir) { 
   $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); 
    foreach ($files as $file) { 
      (is_dir("$dir/$file") && !is_link($dir)) ? delTree("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file"); 
    } 
    return rmdir($dir); 
  }
```