# delete directory in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

iam doing my project in codeigniter in that i used to create new directory to upload my images.now i need to delete my new directory for that i have tired this coding,

```
 $dir = '/var/www/uploads/chat/'.$input['chat_id'];
   system('/bin/rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($dir));
```

but its not working for me.i have got this coding from this link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296681/php-simplest-way-to-delete-a-folder-including-its-contents` what i need to do?

Comment: why don't you try `unlink()` ?

Comment: can u provide sample coding for that

Comment: may i know what is wrong in my coding.

Comment: CodeIgniter has a built-in helper to delete all files inside a folder, Check the [File Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html) and use `delete_files('./path/to/directory/', TRUE);` to delete all files inside then `rmdir('./path/to/directory/')` to delete the directory.

Comment: s hashem i have tried like this $this->load->helper('file');
  delete_files('/var/www/uploads/chat/1/taxi_src.png', TRUE);

Comment: @sangee remove `taxi_src.png` from the end of the path, then use `rmdir()` to remove the user's folder. _The path is relative to your main site index.php file_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are creating the directory use 777 as permission like

```
mkdir('new_dir', 0777, true);
```

and then try the below code

```
if(rmdir('new_dir'))
{
    echo "deleted";die;   
}
else
{
    echo "not deleted";die;
}
```

i checked it and found,if your folder has not right permission then it will not be deleted.

please try and let me know the status.

Comment: $this->load->helper("file");
delete_files(base_url().'/var/www/uploads/chat/1');

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  rmdir(uploads/chat/2): Permission denied</p>
<p>Filename: models/chat_model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 66</p>
i got error like this

Comment: when you created this folder/subfolder i.e uploads/chat/2,have you set permission 0777?because i can see permission denied saying in the model .

Comment: s i gave that permission

Comment: ok, but <p>Message: rmdir(uploads/chat/2): Permission denied</p> this line means your folder dosen't have right permission to delete.