# PHP (WINDOWS) : Delete files and folders without deleting parent directory

Tags: php, delete-file

I need some help, how can i delete files and folders without deleting parent directory. 
 Like I have

```
   D:\test\tester D:\test\test.php D:\test\tester\tester.php
```

I want D:\test remains not deleted.

I tried this code, but it is not deleting recursively.

```
function removeDirectory($path) {
$files = glob($path . '\*');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    is_dir($file) ? removeDirectory($file) : unlink($file);
}
rmdir($path);
return;
}
removeDirectory('D:\image_packer\destination');
```

Comment: with code ... what did you try?

Comment: that wont delete directories

Comment: @Dagon that sir. i edited again

Comment: you want everything under `D:\image_packer\destination` deleted but leave the directory itself?

Comment: @Dagon Yes Sir. That what i really want .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the modified version of the code previously posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13490957/2757528):

```
function rrmdir($dir, $level = 0) { 
  foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) { 
    if(is_dir($file)) rrmdir($file, $level+1); else unlink($file); 
  } 
  if ($level !== 0)
    rmdir($dir); 
}
```

Pass it directory you want to remove and everything but the indicated directory will be deleted