# Delete folder with PHP,JQuery and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this line for delete a folder

```
<button class='elimina' data-elimina='$path/$file'>elimina $path/$file</button>
```

get the folder path via JQuery

```
 $(".elimina").click(function(){
     var data = $(this).data('elimina');
     $.post('file.php',data, function(response) {
        // Log the response to the console
        console.log("Response: "+response);
        });
      });
```

At the last I pass it to my *file.php*

```
$archivo = $_POST['data'];

    rmdir($archivo);
```

But never got pass the *var data* to my php file .I put  an *if(isset($_POST['data'])){echo $_POST['data'];}* and never saw the path,but I now the path arrive to Jquery script (because also tested).

I haven´t  form,only the button,could be it the problem?

Comment: that code is extraordinarily dangerous. you're allowing ANYONE to delete ANY file server for which they know the path and your webserver userID has the rights to.

Comment: Is only for my work,I hope anybody will try nothing dangerous

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
 $.post('file.php',data, function(response) {
                    ^^^^
```

You're not sending a `key:value` pair, you're just sending `value`. With no key, PHP has nothing to use to produce a $_POST entry

You should have

```
 $.post('file.php',{data:data}, function(response) {
                    ^-key  ^--value
```

Comment: I did it,but I still have the same issue,any folder is delete,and I have any echo (I changed it for test)

Comment: @Ini This should have solved the problem, there must be something else you're not showing us. What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: @ini Are you using an absolute path for the directory?

Comment: @ini Is the directory empty? `rmdir()` will only delete an empty directory. If it's not empty, you have to delete everything in it first, and recurse into subdirectories as well.

Comment: rmdir returns boolean false on failure. you should be returning that as well, e.g something as simple as `if(rmdir(...)) { echo 'success'; } else { echo 'failure'; }`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks,it was,the folder isn´t empty.Great!

Comment: @Ini See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296681/php-simplest-way-to-delete-a-folder-including-its-contents/13490957?s=1|3.2892#13490957 for how to recursively delete a folder.